# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in... with IPN

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /homepages/6/d354573317/htdocs/Test/ipn/ipn-handler.php on line 24

I'm trying to connect to the IPN with paypal, to eventually get my transaction data. If anyone could point out where the error is in my code I'd much appreciate it.

Code is:

```
<?php 

class Paypal_IPN
{
    /** @var string $_url The paypal url to go to through cURL
    private $_url;

    /**
    * @param string $mode 'live' or 'sandbox' 
    */
    public function __construct($mode = 'live')
    {
        if ($mode == 'live')
        $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

        else
        $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . ' -- ' . $postFields);
        fclose($fh);

        echo $result;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: whats the rest of the error mesage, it should show file name and line number, posted code loosk ok (I would use braces for the if)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /homepages/6/d354573317/htdocs/Test/ipn/ipn-handler.php on line 24

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Just to make sure line 24 is: `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)` ?

Comment: There aren't any syntax errors in the code sample you provided, at least not with PHP 5.6.4.

Comment: :s im still getting the error. Hence why im so confused lol

Comment: You could just use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). `$postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . http_build_query($_POST);`.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths: Is that the _entire_ error message? If the parser finds something unexpected, it usually tells you what it expected instead. You get a similar error message if you forget the `$` character or leave out the `$key` variable completely.

Comment: @Nisse yes that was the full error message